# Convert String of Racket Source Code into Racket Code

Tags: macros, racket

I'm writing a system where a client sends code to a server (implemented in racket) for execution. The code is received as a string. I need to convert that string into the racket code that it represents and execute it. Any definitions inside of the code need to be available after the code is extracted. When I run the following, I get back `1`, as expected.

```
(define-syntax-parser expand
    ((_) (datum->syntax this-syntax (format-datum '~a "(define (f x) x)"))))
(expand)
(f 1)
```

But if I try to hold the string in a variable `source`, I get back `source: undefined; cannot reference an identifier before its definition`. I understand this is because macros are expanded at compile-time, when `source` has yet to be defined. Does anyone else have any ideas for how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to evaluate a string, then naïvely you want `read` and `eval`.  You certainly don't want a macro.

**Note this is insanely dangerous and almost certainly an extremely bad idea**: running uncontrolled code (or even calling `read` unless you have *absolute faith* in `read`'s safety) that you have been sent by something only makes sense if you have *implicit, total trust* in the thing that sent you the code.  There have been very many famous problems because people abused such trust.  At the very least you should read [Reflection and Security](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/security.html) in the Racket documentation: especially the stuff on sandboxes.  But sandboxed evaluators have also been subject to many famous exploits.

```
;;; May explode if exposed to light.  Hypergolic in air.
;;;

(define string-to-evaluate "
(define-syntax-rule (bind [v val] form ...)
  (let ([v val]) form ...))
(bind (foo 1)
  (+ foo foo))
(define bar 1)
")

(define (evaluate-string s (n (make-base-namespace)))
  (values
   (call-with-input-string
    s
    (λ (p)
      (for/list ([form (in-port read p)])
        (eval form n))))
   n))
```

```
> (evaluate-string string-to-evaluate)
'(#<void> 2 #<void>)
#<namespace>
> bar
bar: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
> (evaluate-string string-to-evaluate (current-namespace))
'(#<void> 2 #<void>)
#<namespace:'anonymous-module>
> bar
1
```

But

```
> (evaluate-string "(require racket/system) (system \"echo now I own your computer\")")
now I own your computer
'(#<void> #t)
#<namespace>
```

Oops.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! And for noting the security concerns. This is just a PoC. Ultimately, our system won't support arbitrary programs. Another approach I landed on was this:

`(define source "(define (f x) x)")(define evaluator (make-evaluator 'racket source))(evaluator 'f(1))`

Would you say one of these approaches is superior to the other?

Comment: @Wowee: I think something using `make-evaluator` is the right approach for sure as it talks about sandboxing, which is what you almost certainly want.  But I'm not familiar with that part of Racket enough to comment in detail on it.

Comment: Any ideas for how you might make `bar` available in a definition file? As far as I can tell, 

`(evaluate-string string-to-evaluate (current-namespace))
(bar)
1`

only works in the REPL.

Comment: You need to use namespace anchors (which don't seem to be well-documented.  But use `make-evaluator`, which is likely to be a lot safer.